# Extracting values from JSON response with PHP

Tags: php, json, curl

I'am sending JSON data to an URL and then I also recieve JSON.
I'm using PHP CURL to recieve the data and show it on my page.
My Problem is that I can only get the json completely and I can't show only a selected value from that JSON data.
I got this already:

```
//API Url
$url = "https://auth.unilinxx.com/test";

//Initiate cURL.
$ch = curl_init($url);

//The JSON data.
$jsonData = array("value" => "Gideon lol");

//Encode the array into JSON.
$jsonDataEncoded = json_encode($jsonData);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
//Tell cURL that we want to send a POST request.
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

//Attach our encoded JSON string to the POST fields.
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $jsonDataEncoded);

//Set the content type to application/json
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/json")); 

//Execute the request
$result = curl_exec($ch);

$values = json_decode($result, true);

echo $values["value"];
```

My result is: `{"value":"U heeft Gideon lol gestuurd."}`

I like to have only this:  `U heeft Gideon lol gestuurd.`

How can I do that?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Comment: I already used that as you can see in my code!

Comment: Are you viewing the JSON string "https://auth.unilinxx.com/test" is outputting to help you see what's going on here?  It looks like your API is returning a nested JSON array of "value"{"value":{"U heeft...

Comment: unless you have json inside json, this is not a correct result

Comment: `echo $values["value"];` would fail if your output was `{"value":"U heeft Gideon lol gestuurd."}` so something tells me this code is not what is being ran or `$values["value"]` is a string of that data structure...

Comment: $result returns {"value":"U heeft Gideon lol gestuurd."}1

Comment: I would suggest that you stop using `!` at the end of all your comments... we are here to help but have questions and need your assistance.

Comment: I suggest you to use guzzle instead of curl :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your entire code is correct you only have to add `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` to `true` in your code. Other wise result will not store in variable. And output to screen directly

```
<?php
//API Url
$url = "https://auth.unilinxx.com/test";

//Initiate cURL.
$ch = curl_init($url);

//The JSON data.
$jsonData = array("value" => "Gideon lol");

//Encode the array into JSON.
$jsonDataEncoded = json_encode($jsonData);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
//Tell cURL that we want to send a POST request.
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

//Attach our encoded JSON string to the POST fields.
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $jsonDataEncoded);

//Set the content type to application/json
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/json")); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); //<---------- Add this line
//Execute the request
$result = curl_exec($ch);

$values = json_decode($result, true);

echo $values["value"];
```

Comment: I am doing the same thing with ajax request, when I just echo the `$results` it gives the json string but when I add  `$values = json_decode($result, true);` jquery console.log returns null why is that?

Answer (score 2):

is your result variable return string? if it just return TRUE or FALSE please try to add this code

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
//API Url
$url = "https://auth.unilinxx.com/test";

//Initiate cURL.
$ch = curl_init($url);

//The JSON data.
$jsonData = array("value" => "Gideon lol");

//Encode the array into JSON.
$jsonDataEncoded = json_encode($jsonData);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
//Tell cURL that we want to send a POST request.
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

//Attach our encoded JSON string to the POST fields.
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $jsonDataEncoded);

//Set the content type to application/json
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/json")); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); //<----- I will add this line
//Execute the request
$result = curl_exec($ch);

$values = json_decode($result, true);
```